# Which conjunction should I use here: "Lasting longer than one hour [and/or] requiring treatment"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, conjunctions

> Any episode lasting longer than one hour **and/or** requiring treatment

Which conjunction should I use here?

Comment: If you mean 'either one or the other or both' it's acceptable to use 'and/or'.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a full sentence, so I'm going to assume that it will read

> Any episode lasting longer than one hour *and/or* requiring treatment should be referred.

As Kate Bunting commented, *and/or* is used to mean "either one or the other or both." It's quite likely that in this case you do mean that.

If you really want to use only one, *or* is probably best, because

> An episode which
>
> - requires treatment, or
> - appears not to require treatment but lasts more than an hour,
>
> should be referred.

"Lasts more than an hour and requires treatment" is covered by the first alternative here, because it requires treatment.

But *and/or* is fine; it's quite usual, and a lot clearer than just using *or* alone, as this demonstrates. There is a lot more mental processing required to determine what should happen if the episode lasts more than hour and requires treatment, if you use only *or.*

Comment: *Or* alone can be inclusive or exclusive; it's possible to parse the original fragment as exclusive (though even after doing so you'd have to be very literal-minded to avoid treatment). *And/or* is unambiguously inclusive, so it's the way to go.

Comment: Marvellously weaselly (and advisable) inclusion of 'appears ... to'.